# getClassDef not found

Tags: c++, r, swig

i have created an R wrapper for a DLL using Swig on Windows.
Latest R version installed on machine.

An r sample just loads the new dll and calls a function for test.
Unfortunately, i get this error:

```
"could not find function getClassDef".
```

The vs2008 project build calls swig.exe which also creates an mydll.r file.
This file lists sum function calls of getClassDef.

The r library linked to the DLL has R_getClassDef.
The question is: where is getClassDef defined.

I put my sample script, the mydll.r into r\bin\x386 where also r.dll is located.
It is version 3.xx

I run the sample with rscript sample.r

Any help appreciated

Comment: Is the methods package loaded when you make your function call?

Answer (score 0):

To find to which package a function is in, use the `find` function.

```
find("getClassDef")
## [1] "package:methods"
```

Comment: Hello,doing so, i get returned character(0) :-(

Comment: @maxchinaski: Did you spell `getClassDef` correctly? And do you have the `methods` package installed?  (If you do, `"methods" %in% .packages(TRUE)` will return `TRUE`.)

Comment: Hello Richie, i wrote a small script :"methods" %in% .packages(TRUE)
find("getClassDef") it returns (TRUE) in 1. line, charactor(0) in 2nd line. I have R 3.01 installed. The script is started with rscript myscript.r